# Twitter Bootstrap Media Grid: square box with images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

This is not really a question, but a solution to a problem I just had. I'm posting it here, because I can imagine others would like to use it.

The problem I had was: I want to show an overview of square image tiles using Twitter Bootstrap (Media Grid module) with a fixed width using the grid system (span2, span3, etc.) without cluttering the markup.

The LESS code below works out of the box and is an extension to the Bootstrap library:

```
.squareColumns(@columnSpan: 1) {
    width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columnSpan) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columnSpan - 1));
    height: (@gridColumnWidth * @columnSpan) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columnSpan - 1));
}

.maxSquareColumns(@columnSpan: 1) {
    max-width: (@gridColumnWidth * @columnSpan) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columnSpan - 1));
    max-height: (@gridColumnWidth * @columnSpan) + (@gridGutterWidth * (@columnSpan - 1));
}

ul.square-media-grid {
    .media-grid;

    li a.span1 { .squareColumns(1); img { .maxSquareColumns(1); } }
    li a.span2 { .squareColumns(2); img { .maxSquareColumns(2); } }
    li a.span3 { .squareColumns(3); img { .maxSquareColumns(3); } }
    li a.span4 { .squareColumns(4); img { .maxSquareColumns(4); } }
    li a.span5 { .squareColumns(5); img { .maxSquareColumns(5); } }
    li a.span6 { .squareColumns(6); img { .maxSquareColumns(6); } }
    li a.span7 { .squareColumns(7); img { .maxSquareColumns(7); } }
    li a.span8 { .squareColumns(8); img { .maxSquareColumns(8); } }
    li a.span9 { .squareColumns(9); img { .maxSquareColumns(9); } }
    li a.span10 { .squareColumns(10); img { .maxSquareColumns(10); } }
    li a.span11 { .squareColumns(11); img { .maxSquareColumns(11); } }
    li a.span12 { .squareColumns(12); img { .maxSquareColumns(12); } }
    li a.span13 { .squareColumns(13); img { .maxSquareColumns(13); } }
    li a.span14 { .squareColumns(14); img { .maxSquareColumns(14); } }
    li a.span15 { .squareColumns(15); img { .maxSquareColumns(15); } }
    li a.span16 { .squareColumns(16); img { .maxSquareColumns(16); } }
    li a.span17 { .squareColumns(17); img { .maxSquareColumns(17); } }
    li a.span18 { .squareColumns(18); img { .maxSquareColumns(18); } }
    li a.span19 { .squareColumns(19); img { .maxSquareColumns(19); } }
    li a.span20 { .squareColumns(20); img { .maxSquareColumns(20); } }
    li a.span21 { .squareColumns(21); img { .maxSquareColumns(21); } }
    li a.span22 { .squareColumns(22); img { .maxSquareColumns(22); } }
    li a.span23 { .squareColumns(23); img { .maxSquareColumns(23); } }
    li a.span24 { .squareColumns(24); img { .maxSquareColumns(24); } }   
    
    li a img { display: block; margin: auto; }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ul class="square-media-grid">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="span3">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/330x230" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="span3">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/80x120" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="span3">
            <img class="thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/230x330" alt="">
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

http://pictat.com/i/2012/1/10/12839test.png

Comment: Can you phrase this as a question and put the solution in an answer. For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/419  and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you basically are constraining height using the span classes in addition to default width constraint that bootstrap provides for thumbnails?  It doesn't seem to be working for me with bootstrap 2.0.1 (even when I change it from media-grid to thumbnails).